# Why do tracking scripts check the protocol when loading external JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, url

All the website trackers, like Google Analytics, have a small script that ads a new script tag with async and deferred that loads a tracking script. Many of them use the following javascript:

```
var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http") + "://google-analytics.com/tracking.js";
```

Why don't they use `//google-analytics.com/tracking.js` instead of trying to figure out if the page is https or http? Is there any browser that does not support the protocol-less url today?

Answer (score 2):

from:
http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Protocol-relative URLs cause an error dialog in IE6

> The reason this doesn’t work in IE6 is that the server is using SNI to
>   deduce what certificate to return. XP (and thus IE6) doesn’t support
>   SNI in the HTTPS stack.

If IE6 is not targeted (which it should likely not be at this point) then protocol-relative should work.